# Trusted Platform Module V1.2

Tags: tpm

I have a TPM v1.2(AT97SC3205T). I want to take ownership of this chip. I studied varies sections of taking ownership command. When I send this command I get a TPM_DECRYPT_ERROR error. So the problem is in the encOwnerAuth or encSrkAuth fields. Someone can help me see how these fields are made? I made the following steps to build them.

1- choice a key(for example "123456").

2- applying OAEP padding scheme to the key; // MGF1,  SHA1,  param = "TCPA".

3- encrypting pad_key using PubEk and RSA(with no padding).

Comment: How are you interfacing with the TPM?

Comment: I'm interfacing via I2C.